# How to implement ternary search in C?

Tags: c, search, ternary-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary search in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385012/ternary-search-in-c)

Write tertiary [ternary] search program.

Notes: Tertiary search is similar to binary search. In binary search we consider two parts of the array and select one part as the next search space. In tertiary search we consider the array in 3 equal parts. For this, we take two "middle" indices, middle1 and middle2 respectively at 1/3 and 2/3 of the array. Then we select one of the 3 parts and continue search in that.

Also, how do I find the time complexity of ternary search in the worst case?

My attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void  tsearch(int *a,int i,int j,int k);
main() {
  int a[30],n,i,k;
        printf("\nEnter n:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("\nEnter nos in ascending order:");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  printf("Enter no to search:");
  scanf("%d",&k);
  tsearch(a,0,n-1,k);

  getch();
}

void tsearch(int *a,int i,int j,int k) {
  int m1,m2;
  m1=(i+j)/3;
  m2=2*(i+j)/3;
  if(k==a[m1])
   {
    printf("\nno found at %d",m1);
    return;
   }
  else  if(k==a[m2])
   {
    printf("\nno found at %d",m2);
    return;
   }
  if(k<a[m1])
    return(tsearch(a,i,m1-1,k));
  if(k>a[m2])
    return(tsearch(a,m2+1,j,k));
  else   
    return(tsearch(a,m1+1,m2-1,k));
}   


***
```

It terminates if number to be searched is present in one of last 2-3 locations (of array). Where have I committed the mistake?

Comment: "Ternary search" may yield better results.

Comment: "plz send teh codez!!1" - not okay on SO. Your most specific question is about worst-case time complexity. Do you also have to implement a tertiary search? What does it operate on? Try asking *specific* questions about how to go about implementing it.

Comment: yes..i want to implement the program of tertiary search for integers!! & i want to know  time complexity of that program for worst case...

Comment: So calculate it....  walk through those loops and figure it out hombre...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for Ternary Search?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

[Case Insensitive Ternary Search Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618086/case-insensitive-ternary-search-tree)

Comment: thnx!!! how to know the time complexity of ternary search in worst case???

Comment: If this is a homework problem, pretty much anyone you ask will tell you it's to your benefit to solve it yourself.